# Node.js: Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I'm having some trouble with regular expressions in Node.js/

This is what I have:

```
Using pin #4
Data (40): 0x1 0xb5 0x0 0xd1 0x87
Temp =  20.9 *C, Hum = 43.7 %
```

I'd like to get the value between Temp= and *C (20.9 in this case) and also the value between Hum = and % (43.7 in this case).

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these pattern:

```
(?<=[ ,]?(?:Temp|Hum)\s*\=\s*)([^\s]+)
```

or:

```
(?:\=\s*)([^\s]+)
```

or:

```
(\d+(\.\d+)?)(?=\s*.?(?:C|%))
```